# Rx Netty: Async client keeps getting "Content stream is already disposed" error

Tags: rx-java, rx-netty

In the code below I'm trying to build a simple async HTTP client using Rx Netty that makes 75 POST requests to an api. The problem I'm having is that I keep getting a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content stream is already disposed." error.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it related to this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty/issues/264

```
NioEventLoopGroup provider = new NioEventLoopGroup();

HttpClient<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> client = new HttpClientBuilder<ByteBuf, ByteBuf>("my-api.com", 80)
    .eventloop(provider)
    .build();

Gson gson = new Gson();

Observable.range(1, 75, Schedulers.from(provider))
    .flatMap(count -> {
      Data data = new Data("test" + count);

      return client.submit(
          HttpClientRequest.createPost("/create")
              .withHeader("Authorization", AUTH_HEADER)
              .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
              .withContent(gson.toJson(data))
      );
    })
    .flatMap(response -> {
      return response.getContent().map((ByteBuf content) -> {
        return gson.fromJson(content.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()), OtherData.class);
      });
    })
    .subscribe(
        data -> logger.info("item done"),
        err -> {
          logger.error("Error", err);

          provider.shutdownGracefully();
        },
        () -> {
          logger.info("done");
          provider.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    );
```

Comment: Is `client` not closed when the result of the `submit()` is complete?

Comment: @BobDalgleish i don't believe so. the error occurs regularly but not all the time. sometimes this code will work without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised that when you do `response.getContent()` it needs to be done inside a map rather than a flatMap. For example:

```
NioEventLoopGroup provider = new NioEventLoopGroup();

HttpClient<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> client = new HttpClientBuilder<ByteBuf, 
ByteBuf>("my-api.com", 80)
.eventloop(provider)
.build();

Gson gson = new Gson();

Observable.range(1, 75, Schedulers.from(provider))
.flatMap(count -> {
  Data data = new Data("test" + count);

  return client.submit(
      HttpClientRequest.createPost("/create")
          .withHeader("Authorization", AUTH_HEADER)
          .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .withContent(gson.toJson(data))
  );
})
// map not flatMap
.map(response -> {
  return response.getContent().map((ByteBuf content) -> {
    return gson.fromJson(content.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()), OtherData.class);
  });
})
.subscribe(
    data -> logger.info("item done"),
    err -> {
      logger.error("Error", err);

      provider.shutdownGracefully();
    },
    () -> {
      logger.info("done");
      provider.shutdownGracefully();
    }
);
```